# YUI3 drag-n-drop demo bug on IE6 (screen turns red&yellow)

Tags: drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-6, yui, yui3

YUI3 is supposed to support IE6 but here is what I try the drag-and-drop demo on IE6:

---

[image: YUI3 drag-n-drop demo bug on IE6, screen turns red yellow]

---

When I begin dragging, the screen turns red and yellow.

Note that I am using IETester (because I don't have an IE6 around) so that might be an IETester bug.

**QUESTION:** Is it something that I can fix by tweaking the YUI3 settings, or a quick modification?
Most of our users come from China, where IE6 is at 37%, so I can't ignore IE6.

**UPDATE:** It also happens on IE8 on the same machine where IETester is installed, but not with IE8 on separate machines, so I guess IETester is messing with the whole system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you mention only happens in IETester, not in IE6.

Comment: Did you test on a real IE6? Thanks a lot! I was afraid it was an artifact of YUI's shim system getting accidentally visible.

Comment: Yes, I had the exact same problem. As I'm running Win7, I used XP Mode to try my pages with IE6.